# Javax pattern validation prints message with escaped backslashes

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, validation

I'm using javax @Pattern annotation to validate a field. I'm using double backslash to escape a backslash character:

```
@Pattern(regexp="^\\+[1-9]\\d{1,14}$", message = "must match format {regexp}")
private String phoneNo;
```

The message I get is:

```
must match format ^\\+[1-9]\\d{1,14}$
```

Why the returned message has double backslashes? They were used just for escaping the characters. It doesn't make sense for the user. I want the message to be:

```
must match format ^\+[1-9]\d{1,14}$
```

I know I can set the specific message, but I want to use the {regexp} argument.

Answer (score 0):

IYou can try to write custom `MessageInterpolator`.

```java
public class MessageInterpolatorImpl implements MessageInterpolator {
    private final MessageInterpolator origin;

    public MessageInterpolatorImpl(MessageInterpolator origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    @Override
    public String interpolate(String messageTemplate, Context context) {
        return interpolate(messageTemplate, context, Locale.getDefault());
    }

    @Override
    public String interpolate(String messageTemplate, Context context, Locale locale) {
        String newMessageTemplate = messageTemplate;
        if (context.getConstraintDescriptor().getAnnotation() instanceof Pattern pattern) {
            String normalizedPattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(pattern.regexp()).toString();
            newMessageTemplate = messageTemplate.replaceAll("\\{regexp}", normalizedPattern);
        }
        return origin.interpolate(
            newMessageTemplate,
            context,
            locale
        );
    }
}

...

@Configuration
class Config {

    @Autowired
    public void tuneValidator(LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactory) {
        MessageInterpolator origin = validatorFactory.getMessageInterpolator();
        validatorFactory.setMessageInterpolator(new MessageInterpolatorImpl(origin));
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for a regular expression when doing the replacement.  Just use `messageTemplate.replace("{regexp}", pattern.regexp())`.